# Deserialize JSON object that has a map using Gson

Tags: java, json, hashmap, gson

I've searched the web for a solution, but, the answers I found only help when the JSON file being parsed is solely a map.

I was wondering if there is a way to parse an object that has an `HashMap` along with other data.

For example:

```
public class Data
{
  String aName;
  HashMap<String, Object> objects;
  List<String> aExpressions;
}
```

I can parse the name and expressions but I don't know how to parse the entire JSON object as a whole.

I think it has something to do with type tokens, but that only works if the whole object is a `HashMap`.

Comment: What do you think JSON is??  It's Lists and Maps and Strings and numbers thrown together using a standard notation.  So long as your List or Map contains (recursively) only Lists, Maps, Strings, Booleans, and numbers (and whatever you use for NULL) it's readily translated into JSON.

Comment: (One problem you have with Java is that the standard Java JSON toolkits obscure the simplicity of the notation.)

Answer (score 1):

The presence of HashMap in your class does not change how Gson converts it to and from json.

```
data d = new data();
//set some values

String json = new Gson().toJson(d);
data d2 = new Gson().fromJson( json, data.class);
```

That's pretty much it.

Comment: +1. As an additional reading to the OP: [How to convert Java object to / from JSON (Gson)](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/)

Answer (score 1):

[Since](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)

> JSON can represent four primitive types (strings, numbers,
>   booleans,    and null) and two structured types (objects and arrays).
>
> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters
>   [UNICODE].
>
> An object is an unordered collection of zero or more name/value
>   pairs, where a name is a string and a value is a string, number,
>   boolean, null, object, or array.
>
> An array is an ordered sequence of zero or more values.

Gson acts 2 ways:

1. you can let Gson deserialize creating a combination of maps, lists and primitives or
2. you can specify exactly the kind of object you want, and through reflection, it will fill the desidered fields.

You can mix these two approaches and of course you can do a lot more to solve all your parsing cases (like using custom type adapters).

I prepared you a little example using your class that shows how Gson can parse your data using a combination of maps/list/primitives or passing your class (that has a mixed approach).

```
package stackoverflow.questions;

import java.util.*;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Q20154323 {

   public static class Data {
      public String aName;
      public HashMap<String, Object> objects;
      public List<String> aExpressions;

      @Override
      public String toString() {
         return "Data [aName=" + aName + ", objects=" + objects + ", aExpressions=" + aExpressions + "]";
      }

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Data d = new Data();
      d.aName = "Test";
      d.objects = new HashMap<>();
      d.aExpressions = new ArrayList<>();

      d.objects.put("key1", 1L);
      d.objects.put("key2", new Date());
      d.aExpressions.add("Stack");
      d.aExpressions.add("Overflow");

      Gson g = new Gson();
      String json = g.toJson(d);
      System.out.println("As JSON: " +json);

      Data d2 = g.fromJson(json, Data.class);
      System.out.println("As \"casted\" data type: " + d2);

      Object o3 = g.fromJson(json, Object.class);
      System.out.println("As \"free\" object: " + o3);

   }

}
```

and this is the execution. It shows you two way of parsing the JSON string that I created using your initial class.

```
As JSON: {"aName":"Test","objects":{"key2":"Nov 23, 2013 1:33:23 AM","key1":1},"aExpressions":["Stack","Overflow"]}
As "casted" data type: Data [aName=Test, objects={key2=Nov 23, 2013 1:33:23 AM, key1=1.0}, aExpressions=[Stack, Overflow]]
As "free" object: {aName=Test, objects={key2=Nov 23, 2013 1:33:23 AM, key1=1.0}, aExpressions=[Stack, Overflow]}
```

You can use one or other approach as your needs.

About the `TypeToken`, due to generics erasure, something like this

```
  List<Data> list = new Gson().parse(aJsonString, List<Data>.class)
```

won't work, you have to do something like

```
  Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Data>>() {}.getType();
  List<Data> list = new Gson().parse(aJsonString, listType.class)
```

but this case applies, pratically, when your JSON is an array and you want to deserialize it into a list of custom classes.